# Solution verification of flux integral $\iint_DF\cdot\hat{n}dS$ with $F=(2x,y,z)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Compute the flux of $F=(2x,y,z)$ through the surface
$$
r = u^2v\,\hat{\imath} + uv^2\,\hat{\jmath} + v^3\,\hat{k},
\quad 0\leq u \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq v \leq 1
$$

My approach: is it correct?[image]

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there other ways to solve this?

Comment: Note that `\imath` produces $\imath$ (without the dot), which makes it much more readable with `\hat\imath`. Compare: $\hat\imath$ vs. $\hat i$. Similarly for `\hat\jmath`: $\hat\jmath$ vs. $\hat j$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.....

Comment: Wow! Two "Math lover"s in the same post. :D